# Local notifications every month except specific date

Tags: ios, swift, localnotification

I have a local notification which repeats every month at a specific day:

```
func setNotifications(date: Date, forMonth: Bool) {
    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()

    center.getNotificationSettings { (settings) in
        if settings.authorizationStatus == .authorized {
            if forMonth == true {
                let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
                content.title = ""
                content.body = "Here is some nice content."
                content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()

                let triggerDate = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day], from: date)
                let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: triggerDate, repeats: true)
                let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "MonthNotification", content: content, trigger: trigger)

                center.add(request, withCompletionHandler: nil)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Let's say the date is 28.01.2018 you will get a notification at 28.02. and so on...

How can I achieve that this notification not appears at another special date (which has this day), for example 28.05.2018?

I hope my question is clear enough.

Comment: If your date example is what you are trying to accomplish, and it will only fire 12 times a year, then I assume that there probably is a handful of dates you do not want the notification to fire on.  You could always check for the next upcoming date and if it is one not to fire on, cancel and reschedule the notification.  It is likely easier to set the notification for each date you would like it to fire on, with separate identifiers.

Comment: @MatthewBradshaw in my case it is only one date in a year where the notification shouldn't trigger. Can you explain how I can check for the next upcoming date?

Comment: You should be able to use `.nextTriggerDate()`.  Check out this link https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/uncalendarnotificationtrigger.  This should allow you to see when the next time the notification is scheduled to trigger.